# Logarithmic integral--

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_c^d\int_a^b\ln|x-y|\ dx\ dy$$

Here we have double integral of a logarithmic function.  I really worked hard but nothing worked out. Any kind of insight, approximation or even document suggestion towards solution of this integral equation will be much appreciated. It's really important part of my electromagnetics exam. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you integrate $\ln |t|$ ?

Comment: I can integrate, but i believe this is whole another case

Comment: Solve the inner integral to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

There are six cases; (i) $a<c<b<d$, (ii) $c<a<b<d$, (iii) $a<c<d<b$, (iv) $c<a<d<b$, (v) $a<b<c<d$, and (vi) $c<d<a<b$.

To facilitate, draw a diagram of the rectangle $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ for each of the four cases and the line $y=x$.

Be careful with respect to the relative order of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ when removing the absolute value signs with $\pm (x-y)$.

For example, in Case (i) for which $a<c<b<d$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_c^d \int_a^b \log|x-y|\,dx\,dy&=\int_b^d \int_a^b \log(y-x)\,dx\,dy\\\\
&+\int_c^b\int_a^y \log(y-x)\,dx\,dy+\int_a^b\int_y^b \log(x-y)\,dx\,dy
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sir thanks for your sincere help, i genuinely do not know the answer, but i will try the method you presented. Your efforts much appreciated.

Comment: Also thanks to Ethan Bolker for nice edit of the question.